# DjangoでTextFieldのdefault値に番号を入れる｡

Tags: python, django

DjangoのModelで変数のdefault値に順番に番号を入れたいです｡  次のようにすればできるかと思ったのですができませんでした｡
なにかいいアイデアはありますか?

```
hoge = models.TextField('hoge', max_length=255, default=lambda: 'hoge' + id)
```